# How do I get response data from php with ajax (one file)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'am trying to get php response data with ajax. I want to check if there is a specific string in `testing.txt` from my input and if the string is found, php should `echo "1"` but no matter what I try AJAX always says `the output isn't 1`

This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['table'])) {
    $file = file("testing.txt");
    if (in_array($_POST['table'], $file)) { 
        echo "1"; 
    } else { 
        echo "0"; 
    } 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<button id="button">NEXT</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var text;
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
        text = document.getElementById('text').value;
        post(text);
    };
    function post(vally) {
        var table = vally;
        $.post('test.php', {table:table}, function(data) {

        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                console.log("the output is 1")
            } else {
                console.log("the output isn't 1")
            }
        });
        console.log('posted');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

testing.txt:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

The response I get if i `console.log(data)`:

```
0<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<button id="button">NEXT</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var text;
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
        text = document.getElementById('text').value;
        post(text);
    };
    function post(vally) {
        var table = vally;
        $.post('test.php', {table:table}, function(data) {

        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                console.log("the output is 1")
            } else {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
        console.log('posted');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using .done(), .fail() and .always() but I always get `the output isn't 1`(I am using JQuery 3.2.1).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I would like to point out something I haven't before. I'm looking for a one page solution. I know that it can easily be done with two pages but I was wondering if there was a one page solution.

Comment: You need to put the PHP in it's own file, or amend the logic flow so that when you call test.php with a `table` value in the request, it *only* returns the `1` or `0` value - ideally in JSON format to avoid any issues with whitespace.

Comment: You actually do good and get the responses. Add exit in the last line of if and it'll work. 

If you wan't to do it better, move php logic that returns response to ajax to a new file without html inside

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because I wanted everything in one file I decided to use `data.slice(0, 1);` to trim off everything except the first character which will be a `0` or `1`, and thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) for reminding me that there may be a whitespace issue, which there was. Now I added `text.trim()` to remove all of the whitespace from the input and `array_filter(array_map('trim', $file));` to remove all of the whitespace from the strings written in the file.

This is the finished code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['table'])) {
    $file = file("testing.txt");
    $file = array_filter(array_map('trim', $file));
    if (in_array($_POST['table'], $file) == true) { 
        echo "1"; 
    } else { 
        echo "0"; 
    } 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text">
<button id="button">NEXT</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var text;
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
        text = document.getElementById('text').value;
        post(text.trim());
    };
    function post(vally) {
        var table = vally;
        console.log(vally);
        $.post('test.php', {table:table}, function(data) {
            var cut = data.slice(0, 1);
            if (cut == 1) {
                console.log("the output is 1")
            } else {
                console.log(cut);
            }
        });
        console.log('posted');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to thank everyone who helped me resolve my issue, which has been bugging me for the last 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Even when it is an old thread I have to answer this post in the right way.

As youve already shown its a possibility to "deconstruct" our response string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AJAX Beispiel</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Dein HTML-Inhalt hier -->

<div id="content">Hello World</div>
<button id="changeTextButton">Text ändern</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#changeTextButton").on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'beispiel.php',
                data: {
                    action: 'changeText'
                }
            })
                .done(function(response) {
                    response = JSON.parse(response.split('\n').slice(-1).join('\n'))
                    console.log(response)
                    $("div#content").text(response.test);
                })
                .fail(function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'changeText') {
    // Hier könntest du ggf. weitere Logik hinzufügen, bevor du den Text zurückgibst
    echo json_encode(["test" => "Neuer Text nach Klick auf Button",
                      "test2" => "Neuer Text2 nach Klick auf Button"]);
    exit();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is just a small example and the file itself is beispiel.php.

Here you have the json part together with the whole html of the page, but still if you "echo" the json data you have the whole json array as 1 row so you can "slice" it and parse it back to json with:

```
response = JSON.parse(response.split('\n').slice(-1).join('\n'))
```

like this you can access the parts as usual, but still this is no nice way.

The normal and clean way is to separate files, but I had the same issue that it is a requirement that this happens in one file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Ajax request is sent to the home page, so it receives everything after '0' or '1'. Split that.

1. Move your PHP code in anoter file, say 'ajax.php'
2. And change your `$.post()` settings to call `ajax.php` instead of `test.php`.

So the Ajax request will only receive the '0' or '1' string.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how your AJAX response is *the entire page*, prepended with the single digit that you're looking for.  You don't need to send the whole page to the browser twice.  Move your PHP logic into its own file with nothing but that logic.  Let's call it `checkTable.php` for the sake of demonstration:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['table'])) {
    $file = file("testing.txt");
    if (in_array($_POST['table'], $file)) { 
        echo "1"; 
    } else { 
        echo "0"; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Then make your AJAX call to that page:

```
$.post('checkTable.php', {table:table})
```

Then the response will contain *only* what that PHP code returns, not the whole page.  (It's worth noting that this PHP code will return an empty response if `table` isn't in the POST data.)

Aside from that, your code is currently returning a `0` for whatever input you're providing, so it's still going to be true that "the output isn't 1".  For that you'll need to double-check your input and data to confirm your assumptions.

Comment: "Aside from that, your code is currently returning a 0 for whatever input you're providing" I just noticed that. I have console logged the input data, and the string in the file should match with the string from the input. I would be interested to know why that it's always returning 0.

Comment: @LeonKunštek: All we could possibly do is guess, we can't see your data.

Comment: I have added the data from my .txt file in the question. If I input any string that is in that file it should return 1 and if I enter anything else it should return 0

Comment: @LeonKunštek: What string are you inputting?  Have you confirmed there isn't a whitespace issue breaking the comparison?